# socket control to accept multiple UDP connections

Tags: c, sockets, epoll, getaddrinfo

I'm breaking my mind trying to understand how make a client/server write by myself accept multiple socket connections.

The connection is a datagram (UDP), for now was implemented based on `getaddrinfo(3) man page` works nice, but each client needs to wait the process of early connections be processed.

I've heard about select, but in its man page says:

> select()  can  be used to solve many problems in a
>          portable and efficient way that naive programmers try  to  solve  in  a
>          more  complicated  manner using threads, forking, IPCs, signals, memory
>          sharing, and so on.

and more:

> The  Linux-specific  epoll(7)  API  provides  an interface that is
>   more
>          efficient than select(2) and poll(2) when monitoring large  numbers  of
>          file descriptors.

So, it is? epoll is simply better than select? Or it depends? If it depends, on what?

epoll man pages has a partial sample, so I'm trying to understand it.

At now, (on server) I think, I need a thread to listen in a thread and write in another. But how to control the completion of a partial message? If two clients send a partial message interleaved, how to identify? By the sockaddr? if it's the only need, I can manage it without a pool, so why use a epoll?

Can anyone try to explain to me, how to make, or where to learn about a multi-connection client-server UDP app?

Comment: 1. Yes, `epoll` is better than `select`. 2. Read the book [Unix Network Programming](http://www.unpbook.com/)

Comment: I'll read it, thanks for response... If you promote your comment to a response, I'll vote it.

Comment: There is no such thing as 'accept[ing] multiple UDP connections'. There is only reading UDP datagrams from one or more remote sources.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think there is a misunderstanding here about UDP. UDP is not a connection oriented protocol which means there is no permanent connection like TCP. UDP just bind to an address/port and waits for packets from everyone. At the server there is only one socket listening per address/port number. When a packet is received you may find out who is the sender by the packet's source IP, you can reply to the sender thru this IP.

As I see it, there is no need for poll() o select() you bind to an address/port and asynchronously receive packets. That is, when a packet is received you get a signal/message alerting your asynchronous function. This function should be reentrant, it means that in the middle of a reception another signal could be received and care must be taken when accessing/modifying global stuff (variables/objects). When dealing with an incoming packet it should be processed as soon as possible or, in case the process takes too long, you better keep the packet in a packet spool and process them in another [less priority] thread.

For UDP packet size read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098897/what-is-the-largest-safe-udp-packet-size-on-the-internet) question.

For UDP fragmentation read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/900697/how-to-find-the-largest-udp-packet-i-can-send-without-fragmenting)

For UDP packet header read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol)