# is there any way to increase the size of a udp packet? java

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sockets, udp

I'm working on a basic udp file transfer code using two emulators on eclipse. From what I've read online on UDP, 64kb can be transferred in one packet. Currently, I am able to transfer about 8kb of data in one packet. is there anyway to increase this number? (to about 30-35kb)

Thanks

Comment: I NEED to work on UDP. please try to avoid telling me that i need to use TCP instead.

Comment: check a similar thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/900697/how-to-find-the-largest-udp-packet-i-can-send-without-fragmenting