# Set DONT_FRAGMENT flag on UDP socket in C++ on OSX

Tags: c++, macos, sockets, udp

I need to set a DONT_FRAGMENT (or analogous) flag on a udp socket. I am using OSX. Looks like DONT_FRAGMENT flag doesn't exist at all. I tried looking on Google and on SO but I only could find a solution that involves the use of raw sockets (the use of which requires administration privileges, which I don't have).

I just can't believe it is impossible to get this done.

Comment: Is it actually useful for anything?  If it works at all, it turns a slower datagram into a discarded datagram.  Is that really what you want?

Comment: I can detect a discarded datagram and improve the quality of my stream of data by reducing the size of the datagrams I send right to the maximum size allowed by MTU.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/900697/how-to-find-the-largest-udp-packet-i-can-send-without-fragmenting

Comment: @willll I am really sorry but I don't get how that answer points out how to set DONT_FRAGMENT flag on osx.